# if $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ is compact, then $E$ is null-set

Tags: measure-theory, volume

I'm trying to understand the validity of this claim and prove it:

if $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ is compact then $\forall \epsilon >0$ there is a finite covering $E \subset \cup_{j=1}^{m} Q_j$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{m}v(Q_j) < \epsilon$

But wouldn't make $E$ a null-set? isn't that the definition of a set that has zero measure?

But for instance, $[0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ is compact, but it is not zero measure. Is this statement even true?

Comment: yes that is the definition of a measure zero set. for compactness one requires only that for every cover there is a finite subcover which includes the given set.

Comment: I know that, that's fine, but the statement then seems wrong. $[0,1]$ is compact, but its not zero measure.

Comment: yes the statement is wrong.

Comment: Are you using Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I don't know which measure I am using. I am only using the definition i was taught which is a null set: $X$ is a null set if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there are open bricks $Q_j$ (perhaps infinitely many) such that $X \subset \cup Q_j$ and $\sum v(Q_j) < \epsilon$

Comment: Doesn't matter which measure I am using, the statement I'm trying to understand doesn't have the word measure in it. It's all volumes of cubes and $\epsilon$s

Comment: The statement is wrong. If you dropped the sum in the last inequality then it would be true.

Comment: @what is $\nu$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your statement is wrong. If $E$ is compact, the only thing you can say is that for any $\epsilon >0$ you can cover $E$ with a finite family of sets such that each of them has measure less than $\epsilon$.

Observe that the cardinality of the covering actually depends on $\epsilon$. Therefore you can't conclude that the measure of $E$ is zero.

Comment: That's fine, but the statement still seems off to me. It basically says you can cover $[0,1]$ using intervals whos lengths sum to $\epsilon$. It doesn't sit well with logic. Is this true?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my answer a bit quickly. As @RobArthan pointed out, your statement is wrong. What I meant to say is that if $E$ is compact, the only thing you can say is that there exists a finite covering of sets such that each of them has length less than $\epsilon$. But of course the number of those sets depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Onil90: understood. Thanks for the clarification.